# Deleting both records in a 1 to 1 relationship

Tags: sql, t-sql

Hi
I have 2 tables A and B. There is a 1 to 1 relationship between A and B. Now say I have a records in A and B (A1 and B1) which are related through this 1 to 1 relationship. How would I delete both records. If I delete A1 1st then I get a conflict error same goes for B1.

I'm just curious

Thank You

Comment: Please supply schema information, such as create table script for your tables and foreign keys. The answer to your question is probably to use cascading deletes.

Comment: The same cannot go for B1, unless you have cyclic FK's which a database should never allow...

Comment: Just curious. How do you add data to your tables with a setup like that? If you can't add you will never have the need to delete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Model the relationship between `A` and `B` in a table `C`. `C` will reference (FK) both `A` and `B`. To remove the relationship, delete the corresponding row in `C`. Whether the entities `A` and/or `B` should also be deleted is then a separate matter.

Comment: Why? 1 to 1(or none) relationships without an intermediary table is perfectly acceptable IMO. It is also great for extending tables where you absolutely cannot change the schema of the primary table.

Comment: @leppie: The question says it all: do it the same table and you get update anomalies e.g. delete the relationship and you also delete the entities etc.

Comment: I dont understand what you are trying to tell me.

Answer (score 0):

What database do you use, MSSQL ORACLE, MySql? Some databases support cascade delete (first two I mentioned support it for sure). Or there is another way, use trigger. Hook it on delete of one which will trigger the seccond, but firstly turn off consistency on those two tables and in the end turn it on.

Edit: If you are using MSSQL then you can set up cascade delete like this. (if your schema is like Table A has Primary key which is the primary/foreighn key in table B )

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[YourTable]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT     
[FK_YourTable1_YourTable2] FOREIGN KEY([YourForeignKey])
REFERENCES [dbo].[YourTable2] ([Id])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO
```

Comment: If your schema is as I think: Table A has Primary key which is the primary/foreighn key in table B, then you can use the above edited sql to set up cascade delete.